# Java : incompatible types error

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I have the following code;

```
for(Object[] myObj : queryResponse.getRecords()) {

}
```

The signature of `getRecords()` is `List<T> getRecords()`

Now queryResponse is of custom type QueryResponse class with 2 members;

```
private Long totalRecords;
    private List<T> records;
```

Now at runtime (during debug), I get the "records" as Vector with members as

```
[0] = Object[]
[1] = Object[]
```

But Iam not sure why i am getting the incompatible types compile error for the following line

```
for(Object[] myObj : queryResponse.getRecords()) {
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Object obj` instead of `Object[] obj` in the `for` loop?

Comment: What's the signature of the `getRecords()` method?

Comment: It is List<T> getRecords()

Comment: Vector... ouch. Is this java 1.4?

Comment: So use List l:queryResponse.getRecords()

Comment: But I am getting the response from query execution and it shows the records as Vector and members as [0] = Object[], [1] = Object[] etc

Comment: and what type arguments did you pass to your `QueryResponse` instance?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to change method declaration from `List<T> getRecords()` to `List<T[]> getRecords()`

I usually do it in Dao layer like :

```
List<Object[]> list = query.list(); // Use vector in your case, I get List<Object[]>
for (Object[] obj : list) {
   //....
}
```